# Python Appending data to dataframe in chunks from requests with limited connection number

Tags: python, pandas, python-requests, python-asyncio

I think this is a basic solution, but I'm struggling to wrap my head around how to create the connection pools and bring the data back. I'm hoping that typing this out will give me some clarity, and if not maybe someone else can!

I have a large (1.7mil row) dataframe with ID numbers. I populate a url with those id numbers to generate a request to get a json. I can only initiate 100 connections at a time to the server I am getting the json from. I then do some parsing and storing of the json data back to the dataframe. From there, I submit the data in batches of 10k records to an api to be stored.

A rough version of what I have so far. I am iterating over the df using iloc in 10k record slices. From there I need to perform the data collection in pools of 100 before submitting the 10k batch to the recieving api.   This is where I am struggling.

I don't need to keep the data after it has been submitted to the api, just a record of what range was submitted, and any ranges that had failures. (Maybe even a list of row['id'] that don't have a 200 response.)

Desired outcome is that each batch of 10k id's are processed with connection pools limited to 100  at a time

Do I need to turn my second for loop into a function, and then call it from asyncio somehow within the first loop?

```
import pandas as pd, math, requests
df=[] #1.7 million records with id numbers

df_len = len(df)
chunk_size = 10000
con_num = 100

for index in range(0, df_len, chunk_size): #iterate through records in 10k chunks
    low = index
    high = index+chunk-1
    if high > df_len:
        high = df_len

#create connection pool here? - documentation says limited to 100 connections/requests at a time

    for x, row in df.iloc[low:high].iterrows(): #iterate through individual records to get json data
        id = row['id']
        try:
            r=requests.get(f'url{id}')
            j = r.json()
            df.loc[x,'Data'] = j['data']

#submit batches of 10k records to api

    df2=df.to_dict(orient="records")
    r=requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(df2))
```

Comment: API servers usually have limits of "n requests per second / minute / hour". In your case, is 100 simultaneous connections or 100 requests per (second / minute / hour)?

Comment: The  documentation isn't clear. It references limits for different tier users in random places. I may not be limited at all. But I did find a case where another user found that only 100 concurrent downloads were allowed.  So maybe that would be a better wording of the step I am struggling with.